# How can I access an email and get the inbox messages via pop3 or imap using R language?

Tags: r, imap, pop3

If I want to check the inbox of my outlook email using R, via pop3 or imap, how can I do it?
I need to download (automatically) some attachments from email inbox to RStudio

Comment: I don't see any current R packages for this; but _why would you want to?_

Comment: @Max I need to download (automatically) some attachments from inbox to RStudio

Comment: Could you write a script in some other language, like Python or Java, and put them somewhere in the file system for R to access?

Comment: Maybe it is an option

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but it might be useful for future visitors.

Since 2019 you can use `mRpostman` for executing IMAP commands from inside R. It is possible to do mailbox operations, message searching and fetching etc. Since version 0.3.0, you can download attachments as well.

**EDIT MARCH 2021**

From version v0.9.X onwards, mRpostman started to adopt `R6` syntax. Therefore, most of the functions from previous versions became methods. That means they now should be called in the `connection_object$method()` fashion.

A simple (UPDATED) example of how to download attachments combined with a previous message search using a date criterion (messages sent on a specific date) would be:

step 1) configure your connection to the Outlook server:

Note that the url `"imaps://outlook.office365.com"` is the default for servers that use Office 365.

```
con <- configure_imap(url="imaps://outlook.office365.com",
                  username="your_user@company.com",
                  password=rstudioapi::askForPassword())

#  other IMAP providers that were tested: Hotmail ("imaps://imap-mail.outlook.com"),
#  Gmail (imaps://imap.gmail.com), Yahoo (imaps://imap.mail.yahoo.com/), 
#  AOL (imaps://export.imap.aol.com/), Yandex (imaps://imap.yandex.com)
```

step 2) Select "INBOX" folder

```
con$select_folder(name = "INBOX")
```

step 3) Search messages by specific criterion/criteria, say messages received on a specific Date

```
res1 <- con$search_on(date_char = "02-Jan-2020")
```

step 4) **Alternative 1**:  Fetch message content (text or body) + extract attachments

```
con$fetch_text() %>% # or with fetch_body()
  con$get_attachments()
```

step 4) **Alternative 2**: Directly fetch attachments

```
con$fetch_attachments()
```

Different approach with the pipe `%>%` operator:

```
con$search_on(date_char = "02-Jan-2020") %>%
  con$fetch_text() %>% # or with fetch_body()
  con$get_attachments()

# OR

con$search_on(date_char = "02-Jan-2020") %>%
  con$fetch_attachments()
```

As a result, in all these examples, `mRpostman` will create a "user@server.com/INBOX" directory containing sub-folder(s) matching your message's (or messages') id(s). Inside the sub-folder(s) you will encounter the attachments.

**Note:** If you are trying to fetch large files (and consequently large messages), it might be necessary to increase your `timeout_ms` and/or `buffersize` argument inside `configure_imap()`.

[image]

For a thorough introduction to mRpostman's functionalities, please refer to the package's official website: https://allanvc.github.io/mRpostman/

**EDIT 2:**

It was asked whether it is possible to search by timestamp. Although the IMAP protocol does not support this kind of search, there is a hacky approach to achieve that. Let's suppose we wanted to search all messages received exactly at "07:30" a.m. since "03-Mar-2021".

```
con$search(AND(
   since(date_char = "03-Mar-2021"),
   string(expr="07:30", where = "HEADER Date")
))
```

Comment: Thank you Allan! Is it possible to search based on a date / timestamp?

Comment: I receive the following error when running this code to get email attachments: Error in get_attachments(.) : could not find function "get_attachments".

Comment: With regard to the error you mentioned, it was due to the fact that my answer was outdated. Since version 0.9.X, `mRpostman` uses `R6` syntax. My answer is now updated with the new syntax approach, including an example with a search based on date. If it was useful, please don't forget to upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Matt. You're welcome! It is possible to search by date, but not by timestamp. According to the RFC 3501, the IMAP protocol does not support this type of search. However, there is a hacky approach to achieve this with a custom search combo of `since/before/on()` + `string()`. I've added that to my answer above.